# Normal line to another

Tags: tikz-pgf

First, I want to say I´ve been looking an answer in this forum but I didn´t find it. My issue is that I don´t know how to do a normal line to an other that I named with "name path=chord". My objective is make lines through node "cent". Is that possible? I mean, I can use relative names like "cent" and "chord" to do lines between them? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[rotate=6.7,line width=0.5pt,fill=black!9.9] plot[] file {S809.41.txt};

\draw [name path=chord,rotate=6.7] (3.41,0)--(0,-0.0000698) node (cent)[pos=0.75]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the content of the text file graphically?

Comment: Do you mean something like `\draw (2.3,3.2) -- (cent.center);`?

Comment: Is a 2D plot. I want to plot a wing profile and its forces. For that reason I want to plot lines  through "cent". I would like to know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It´s something like this. But I would like to control line length without using point coordinate. And I want to know if there is a package to do orthogonal lines between lines that has been named before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. For the first part, you could use polar coordinates; something as

```
\draw (<name>) -- +(<angle>:<length>);
```

which draws a line segment at `<angle>` degrees from `<name>` and having a length given by `<length>`.

For the other part (draw a perpendicular to a given line), you can use either the `calc` library and

```
\draw ( $ (<name1>)!(<name2>)!(<name3>) $ ) -- (<name2>);
```

since `( $ (<name1>)!(<name2>)!(<name3>) $ )` gives the projection of `(<name2>)` on the line from `(<name1>)` to `(<name3>)`, or the `tkz-euclide` package. The example below shows both options:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[rotate=6.7,line width=0.5pt,fill=black!9.9] plot[] file {S809.41.txt};
\draw [name path=chord,rotate=6.7] (3.41,0)--(0,-0.0000698) node (cent) [pos=0.75]{a};
\foreach \angle in {0,20,...,340}
  \draw[cyan] (cent.center) -- +(\angle:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
point/.style={
circle,
inner sep=1pt,
fill,
label=$#1$
}
]
\node[point=a] at (0,0) (a) {};
\node[point=b] at (4,2.5) (b) {};
\node[point=c] at (4,1) (c){};
\node[point=d] at (1,3) (d){};

\draw[cyan] (a) -- (b);
\draw[orange] ( $ (a)!(c)!(b) $ ) -- (c);
\draw[magenta] ( $ (a)!(d)!(b) $ ) -- (d);
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){a}
\tkzDefPoint(4,2.5){b}
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){c}
\tkzDefPoint(1,3){d}
\tkzDrawLine[color=cyan](a,b)
\tkzDrawPoints(a,b,c,d)\tkzLabelPoints(a,b,c,d)
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through c](a,b)
\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.1 and -0.5,color=orange](c,tkzPointResult)
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through d](a,b)
\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and -1,color=magenta](d,tkzPointResult)
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I have other problem... When I defined a node in pos=0.75 and then I use "\draw (<name>) -- +(<angle>:<length>);" that line don´t star exactly from the node "cent". I don´t know why.

Comment: @FJSJ that is because a node has an inner and and outer sep; you can use the `center` anchor for the node: `\draw (cent.center) -- (30:4cm);` or you can declare the node using `node (cent) [pos=0.75,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{}` and then simply `\draw (cent) -- (30:4cm);`.